# Custom action of yii\rest\ActiveController that reads JSON input

Tags: json, rest, yii2

I have registered [`yii\web\JsonParser`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-jsonparser) as an application request’s parser in order to [enable JSON input](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#enabling-json-input):

```
'request' => [
    'parsers' => [
        'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
    ]
]
```

Now, I want my custom action to handle JSON requests like the following one:

```
{
    "one": 11,
    "two": 2,
    "three": 33
}
```

I am doing this by using [`bodyParams`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$bodyParams-detail) ([source](https://onezeronull.com/2022/06/11/adding-custom-action-to-yiirestactivecontroller/#parsing-json-input) of this idea):

```
$bodyParams = Yii::$app->request->bodyParams;

$one = $bodyParams['one'] ?? false;
$two = $bodyParams['two'] ?? false;
$three = $bodyParams['three'] ?? false;
```

The whole controller's code looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace api\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\User';
    
    public function verbs()
    {
        $verbs = parent::verbs();
        $verbs['test'] = ['GET'];
        return $verbs;
    }
    
    public function actionTest()
    {
        $bodyParams = Yii::$app->request->bodyParams;
        
        $one = $bodyParams['one'] ?? false;
        $two = $bodyParams['two'] ?? false;
        $three = $bodyParams['three'] ?? false;
        
        return [
            'params' => [
                'one' => $one,
                'two' => $two,
                'three' => $three,
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing so (i.e. reading JSON directly as action's parameters etc.)?

Comment: I don't think you can get them as action's parameters because those are set from route. I don't know what exactly you expect as "better way of doing so". You can use `$one = $this->request->getBodyParam('one', false);` instead of array and `??` operator.

Comment: You may find inspirational JSON fields (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-resources#fields) or collections (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-resources#collections). These allow mapping of AR models to JSON data. But I am not sure whether this is what you are looking up to.

Comment: @lubosdz Thanks for your idea, but I am already aware of these and I am using these for my models. Here I am asking about completely custom actions and parameters, i.e. the one that has nothing to do with models or that are asking for too complex model relations to be able to express them using simple `fields()` mapping.